# Send email from custom object (Lightning Experience - no URL hacks avail)

Tags: visualforce, email, custom-object, custom-button, lightning-experience

I'm currently trying to add the feature of sending an e-mail from a custom object in LEX. However all the results I found were either related to sending a specific template or using hacks (which is not available in Lightning Experience).
Could anyone explain the best way to implement this in Lightning Experience?

EDIT* Changed LEX to Lightning Experience

Comment: Maybe consider changing LEX to "Lightning Experience" in your question. Some people may confuse it with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_(software) =s

Comment: If somebody knows that this is not possible or requires custom development and much time, this information would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible without any hacks.

Steps:

1. Go to your page layout for your custom object.
2. Click on the wrench in the page layout labeled "Salesforce1 and Lightning Experience Actions."  You will see multiple actions fill in.

[image: SF1 & Lightning Actions Detail]
In the above Screen grab, I had already added it, please proceed with next steps.

3. Go to the "Salesforce1 and Lightning Actions" pane.
4. Add the Send Email Action to the page actions.

[image: SF1 & Lightning Actions]

5. Navigate to your page and send email should be available (if it's not, make sure, if you are in a sandbox you have send all messages for deliverability settings).

[image: Send Email Action from object]

PS. If you users would like to insert a template, change markup, add attachments or preview, they should use the icons next to the send button.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Salesforce help: Integrated Email - Supported Objects

[Productivity Features: What’s Not in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=lex_gaps_limitations_productivity.htm&language=en_US)

"Integrated Email is fully supported for the Account, Campaign, Case, Contact, Leads, and Opportunity objects only, and not for custom objects"